# Length of tube with holes in relation to fluid inlet pressure

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, pressure

I have a pipe with holes all the way through. It is supplied with water under pressure and I want to determine the formula that allows me to combine the length of the tube L the diameter d and D and the number of nozzles. Can anyone help me with this?
[image]

Comment: Are you intending to include viscous effects, or are you treating the fluid as inviscid?

Comment: I should include viscous effects